# How to get the number of lines of data in CSV file in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to get the number of lines of data in several CSV files in VBA.
Here is the code.

```
Sub Woo_Products()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim flds As Folders
Dim fls As Files
Dim strText As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim extfind As String
Dim FilePath As String
Dim sLineOfText As String

On Error Resume Next

Workbooks.Open Filename:="F:\Work\scrape\" & "woocommerce-products.csv", UpdateLinks:=3

Set fls = fso.getfolder("C:\Users\star\Downloads").Files
k = 2
For Each f In fls
    strText = f.Name
    extfind = Right$(strText, Len(strText) - InStrRev(strText, "."))
    If extfind = "csv" Then
        FilePath = "C:\Users\star\Downloads\" & strText

        Open FilePath For Input As #1
        i = 0
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, sLineOfText
            If sLineOfText <> "" Then i = i + 1
        Loop
        Close #1

    End If
Next

Windows("woocommerce-products.csv").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Save
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

But I am getting the same count for each file.
Of course, each file has different lines of data.
Hope to help me for this.

Comment: Don't ever use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This line hides all error messages until `End Sub` but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. This way you cannot find your errors in the code because you cannot see them, you are just blind. Remove that line first, to see which errors you get, otherwise you cannot fix them. • Also I don't see where you use/output  the counted lines. It seems you count them but don't do anything with that count.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I will remove the line.

Comment: You never do something with the linecount `i` ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. If you want, I can share my full source code.

Comment: Do you have teamviewer?

Comment: If your code is not complete: Add the part where you use `i`. As the loop itself looks okay, I suspect that you are using the result outside of the `for each` loop or something. Please share your code to the whole community - the idea of SO is not only to help a single person but to show solutions to all who might have a similar problem.

Comment: If you simply add a statement `Debug.Print i; f.Name` right after the close statement: What is written to the immediate window? Always the same number?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173824/discussion-between-d-sean-and-funthomas).

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is a line count, I would write a function to return the count.

```
Function getFileLineCount(FullFileName As String, Optional LineDelimiter As String = vbNewLine) As Long
    Dim text As String
    Dim fileNo As Integer, n As Long
    fileNo = FreeFile
    Open FullFileName For Input As #fileNo
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, text
        n = n + 1
    Loop
    Close #fileNo
    getFileLineCount = n
End Function
```

Comment: FilePath = "C:\Users\star\Downloads\" & strText
        
        Open FilePath For Input As #fileNo
        i = 0
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, sLineOfText
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        Close #fileNo

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i am still getting the same number. sorry.

Comment: My function works properly.  You should test it on too separate files in the immediate window.  In this way, you can see if the files are actually have the same number of lines or that there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: thanks very much. I'd like you to review my code and provide me your kind instruction. here is the code. http://rextester.com/l/visual_basic_online_compiler

Comment: You reset the line number `i` during each iteration.  There is no way for me to see how you are testing the line count.  I assume that you have a breakpoint set at `Close #1`.  If that is the case I would also have to assume that the files do indeed have the same number of lines.

Comment: the csv files have different number of lines. really.

Comment: Please, don't write *still not working*. This means nothing to us. Tell us what is does. We have no crystal ball. Btw: your links to rextester points to a stub of `VB.net`, not to any VBA.

Comment: @D.Sean Your files might be double delimited.  They might be using commas to limit the columns and semicolons to delimit the rows.  I would start recording a macro, import a file into Excel, and then inspect the Macros Code.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach using `FileSystemObject`:

```
Public Function GetLineCount(ByVal Path As String) As Long
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        GetLineCount = UBound(Split(.OpenTextFile(Path, 1).ReadAll, vbNewLine)) + 1
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: oh, i am sorry for my mistake. i mean it outputs the same count for all files.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the references (Tools --> References)

```
Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5
```

This will count "Return & NewLine" characters in the file.

```
Private Function LineCount(ByVal PathFile As String) As Long
    Dim sData As String
    Dim oFile As New FileSystemObject
    sData = oFile.OpenTextFile(PathFile, ForReading).ReadAll

    Dim oRegX As New RegExp
    oRegX.Pattern = "\r\n"
    oRegX.Global = True
    LineCount = oRegX.Execute(sData).Count + 1

    Set oRegX = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: please take attention that the files are normal files. they are csv files.

Comment: Not sure what your stating: "are normal files."  If you mean that you need to filter just csv files, that is done in your loop already.  This is just a function that does your count.  To test it out just do: `Sheet1.Cells(2, 1) = LineCount(YourFile)`

Answer (score -1):

i = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

It's working so well.

Comment: Thanks everyone.
Keep in touch.
Have a nice day.
Cheers